# For which real $k$ do we have $k^nA^n\to0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not understand how to obtain the set of values for k. Here is the question:

> Determine the set of values of the real constant k such that $k^nA^n$ tends to the zero matrix as n $\rightarrow$ $\infty$.

From the previous section of the question, I have obtained the invertible matrix P and diagonal matrix D. They are

P =$\begin{pmatrix} -17&-1&1\\ 6&2&0\\ 7&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and D =$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&5^n&0\\ 0&0&7^n\end{pmatrix}$

I understand that $k^nA^n = P\begin{pmatrix} k^n&0&0\\ 0&k^n5^n&0\\ 0&0&k^n7^n\end{pmatrix} P^{-1}$ but I do not know how to continue. Please help.

Comment: So, for what values of $k$ do the sequences $k^n$, $k^n5^n$, and $k^n7^n$ all converge to zero?

Comment: hmm I got -1 < k < 1? but from the answer sheet, its $\frac{-1}{7}$ < k < $\frac{1}{7}$. I don't understand why. Can someone please explain to me why?

Comment: If $k$ is, say, $1/2$, does $k^n7^n$ converge to zero?

Comment: Oh, yes I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write up a solution, and to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k^nA^n$ to converge to the zero matrix, $k^n, k^n5^n$ and $k^n7^n$ must all converge to zero.

For $k^n, k^n5^n$ and $k^n7^n$ to converge to zero when n $\rightarrow\infty$ , the value of k, 5k and 7k must be between -1 and 1. Since 7 is the greatest number in the diagonal matrix, the maximum value of k will correspond to that number.

Therefore, $$-1 < 7k < 1$$ 
$$\frac{-1}{7} < k < \frac{1}{7}$$